# mule server auto deployment details

Tags: mule

I am using mmc for deployment of mule based application. All deployed application through mmc goes to apps directory under mule server. If I put an application directly under mule-server/apps, launch the application, application runs successfully, but I am not able to view the deployment details in mmc. Where I need to make the changes in mule server to view the deployed application details in mmc?

I need to make a auto deployment through shell script. For this, I am creating a sample project, create zip file, copy this zip file under mule server apps direction. Finally, once mmc is launched, I need to see the deployed application in mmc for viewing flows, running application, flow analyzer etc.

**EDIT**

Based on answer given below to deploy a new application, I have given my url as:

`curl --basic -u admin:admin -F file=@C:/apps/testserver-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip -F name=test-app -F version=2.0 --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' http://almule1.ux.corp.local:8585/mmc/api/repository`

Response I received:

`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: multipart {"versionId":"local$5015b8d6-b149-4245-a218-55c12aecc8e7","applicationId":"local$74616cb9-9ecb-4fd6-b167-bf153c8e59fb"}`

I am using windows env to deploy in unix server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MMC retrieves information from Mule ESB, so you shouldn't make any changes. Anyway I think that deploying an application outside MMC is not a good idea. For scripting purposes I would prefer to use [MMC Deployments REST API](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deployments). You can deploy an application by simply running:

#### Upload zipped application

This uploads your application to MMC.

```
    curl --basic -u admin:admin -F file=@my-zipped-app.zip -F name=test-app -F version=2.0 --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/repository
```

#### List available servers

```
    curl --basic -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/mmc-console-3.4.0/api/servers
```

There you should get the server Id (let's suppose it is local$26f2fea8-3b7c-45a7-84a8-d1509e73fca4), then use it in this command:

#### Create deployment

Before starting your application you need to create a deployment telling MMC to which server, and the id of the uploaded application.

```
    curl --basic -u admin:admin -d '{"name" : "ExampleDeployment" , "servers": [ "local$26f2fea8-3b7c-45a7-84a8-d1509e73fca4" ], "applications": [ "local$32bb47d3-d180-4bb9-8906-2378dad9ae21" ]}' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/deployments
```

#### Perform deploy

Once you have a server and a deployment you can finally start the application.

```
    curl --basic -u admin:admin -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/deployments/local$97e3c184-09ed-423e-a5a5-9b94713a9e36/deploy'
```

Comment: but, whatever changes made in mmc console, should be reflected in some files, mostly xml files. I want to know the file name.

Comment: No, there are no xml files to track server information. You can query most of it through JMX. The rest of the information is polled by MMC but there are no files where data is stored.

Comment: How do I deploy a new application in mule server using mmc deployment? when I run command curl --basic -u admin:admin locnhttp://almule1.uxs.corp.local:8585/mmc/api/deployments it does list the deployed existing application details, ie. it lists all the application which I had deployed manually through mmc. I need to deploy a new application through REST api call without using mmc? I am not able to find the application id for my new application. How did you get application id for a new application? i.e. in your code you mentioned applications": [ "local$32bb47d3-d180-4bb9-8906-2378dad9ae21" ]

Comment: are you properly escaping symbols? Are you using windows?

Comment: Yes, I have changed and and updated my reponse above. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the auto deployment on windows environment which deploys in Unix server.

Application Name: testserver-1.0.zip

step1: Upload

`curl --basic -u admin:admin -F file=@C:/apps/testserver-1.0.zip -F name=auto-deploy-server -F version=1.0 --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" http://allmule1.ux.corp.local:8585/mmc/api/repository`

Response:

```
{"versionId":"local$fd507b45-25c2-4cc9-afe9-9f020f685867","applicationId":"local$47bcf1f3-72bc-4c08-ba50-4fe33422199c"}
```

step2: Get server details:

```
curl --basic -u admin:admin http://allmule1.ux.corp.local:8585/mmc/api/servers
```

Response:

```
{"total":1,"data":[{"agents":[{......,"agentUrl":"https://localhost:7777/mmc-support","version":"3.4.2","name":"Mule-3.4.2","id":"local$5a6c4f81-7b35-425d-95bd-200224f60a2b"}]}
```

Note: Here server id is: local$5a6c4f81-7b35-425d-95bd-200224f60a2b
Get the VERSION ID (not application id) from step 1

step3: deployments

```
curl --basic -u admin:admin -d  "{\"name\" : \"Auto-Deployment\" , \"servers\": [ \"local$5a6c4f81-7b35-425d-95bd-200224f60a2b\" ], \"applications\": [ \"local$fd507b45-25c2-4cc9-afe9-9f020f685867\" ]}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://allmule1.ux.corp.local:8585/mmc/api/deployments
```

Response:

```
{"applications":["local$fd...,"name":"Auto-Deployment","id":"local$9062bbe7-75ab-4658-b021-8314b1681511","lastModified":"Wed, 18 Jun 2014 12:27:30.610 PDT"}
```

Note here Deployment Id: local$9062bbe7-75ab-4658-b021-8314b1681511

Step4: Deploy

```
curl --basic -u admin:admin -X POST http://allmule1.ux.corp.local:8585/mmc/api/deployments/local$9062bbe7-75ab-4658-b021-8314b1681511/deploy
```

Response: The deployments were deployed

verify your server console, application might have deployed.

Redeploy

curl --basic -u admin:admin -X POST http://allmule1.ux.corp.local:8585/mmc/api/deployments/local$9062bbe7-75ab-4658-b021-8314b1681511/redeploy

Undeploy:

curl --basic -u admin:admin -X POST http://allmule1.ux.corp.local:8585/mmc/api/deployments/local$9062bbe7-75ab-4658-b021-8314b1681511/undeploy

Answer (score 0):

Automated Deployment with Mule Management Console and Maven
https://dzone.com/articles/automated-deployment-mule?mz=38541-devops